# In Maven how can I recursively build -SNAPSHOT dependencies present in the filesystem but outside the reactor?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have two projects as follows, in neighbouring directories on the filesystem:

- project_a (-SNAPSHOT)
- project_b (-SNAPSHOT, depends on project_a)

I'd like to build project_b and for Maven to discover that project_a exists on the filesystem and thus build it rather than look in the local repo for its artifact.

I could build these within an aggregator and use the reactor to select project_b i.e.

```
mvn --projects project_b [goal]
```

However, this is problematic because

- this two-project example is a simplification of my real build, which consists of dozens of projects, and I don't want to have to maintain an aggregator project that lists all of them.
- I only want to recursively build -SNAPSHOT dependencies

Is there a neat way I could get Maven to perform a recursive build that looks on the filesystem to find -SNAPSHOT dependency projects and builds them?

Comment: Do those project belong together in the meaning of releasing or are they really separate ? Have you thought about a multi-module build?

Comment: khmarbaise, the projects have inter-dependencies but I want them built separately in most cases to avoid a monolithic build. I have thought about a multi-module build. It's not appropriate here, as far as I can see

Answer (score 2):

I needed this a while back and made a simple recursive wrapper cli in nodejs. https://github.com/kenglxn/mvnr/blob/master/README.md

Install from npm with

```
sudo npm install -g mvnr
```

Then just pass any maven command to mvnr, and it will run that command on all mvn projects under the cwd.

Answer (score 1):

You could play with [Maven Reactor plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-reactor-plugin/index.html), e.g. try `mvn reactor:make -Dmake.folders=foo,bar`

Comment: Thanks Eugene. When I try to use mvn reactor:make, it appears the plugin fails because of an internal error (it's trying to invoke Maven with incorrect command-line options):

`[INFO] --- maven-reactor-plugin:1.0:make (default-cli) @ tgv ---
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "C:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\mvn.bat -B -N -r -D maven.reactor.includes=tgv-client\pom.xml install"
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: -r`